# Why appears undefined?

Tags: javascript

I have this code to show the result of the test() function. The test function uses the biggestNumber() function. But it's not working, the console log shows undefined. Do you know why?

```
window.onload = function() {

  console.log(test());

}

function biggestNumber(num1, num2) {
  if(num1>num2){
    console.log(num1);
  }
  else if(num1<num2){
    console.log(num2);
  }
  else{
    console.log(num1);
  }

}

function test() {
  var num1 = parseInt(prompt("Num1"));
  var num2 = parseInt(prompt("Num2"));

  var result = biggestNumber(num1,num2);
  console.log(result);  
}
```

Comment: neither of these functions returns anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its very simple and basic. If a function doesnt `return` something it will automatically return `undefined`.

`biggestNumber` doesnt have an `return` so its returning undefined

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Math.Max()` you can find the largest number in an array.

```
const array1 = [1, 3, 2];

console.log(Math.max(...array1));
```

you can use the `...` before the array name there to "unpack" the array.